# how to send an SMS without opening other app in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to send SMS directly from my flutter app like by clicking button and enterning reciever's number but without opening any other or default sms app. I have already try many packages like url_launcher,flutter_sms but they generally redirect to other app.

If someone knows how to do it, please answer.
Answer in code will be more helpful.

Thank you in advance........

Comment: Use a 3rd party sms provider

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to do directly from app. 
You could use some 3rd party service, such as Twillio. So you would send API call to that service and Twillio would take care of rest.

But why do you need to do so? This is not what usual user expects from the app. It would look like some number stealing app.
I suggest you to use regular way, which is used in the most apps.

Comment: Thanks for your advice i will try to use twilio api. I want sms feature for my final year project in which in case of emergency app will automatically detect accident based on some parameters and send sms to saved contact numbers inside my app.

Comment: Hello Shivam, I am trying to implement a very similar application. What method did you eventually use to implement this?